# StyleFunction Openlayers-3 - multiple callback variables?

Tags: openlayers

I am using the "styleFunction" from the following example: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/examples/geojson.html

```
var styleFunction = function(feature, resolution){
    var properties = feature.getProperties();
    var type = feature.getGeometry().getType();
    switch (type) {
        case 'Point':
        ...return some styling...
        break;
        case 'Polygon':
        ...return some styling...
        break;
    }
}
```

I am currently using only the "feature" from the callback. I can't seem to find documentation about this function on Openlayers.org so I ask here:

Are there more variables available for callback and is there a way to find out without documentation?

(I need to know the layer name the function is styling, and I can't get that from the feature alone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no more variables on callback. To solve your question just store the layer name on feature and then get it back on callback.

```
//before you add ol.Feature to ol.source.Vector
feature.set('layer-name', layerName);
```

Get it back on styleFunction:

```
feature.get('layer-name');
```

Comment: This is not working, because I only have 1 feature :( I will try to create a JSfiddle for it.

Comment: Here we go: http://jsfiddle.net/8hgxyayp/6/ As you can see in the GeoJSON, each feature has the same properties with different values. These values represent the radius of hte circle. But I can't get to those values, because when the styleFunction runs, there is only 1 layername available...

Comment: I don't understand your logic. The layer name is supposed to be like an ID but you are using the **key** of the property, instead of **value**. In my first example was the value of category property.

Comment: Like `var category = feature.get('desc');` in your fiddle.

Comment: Oh, I didn't say unlogical, it is just I don't understand it. Now look, all you have to do is ***set a unique parameter to the layer and store it into the feature***

Comment: Aaaah now I understand :D

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8hgxyayp/7/ I give up... I still am not able to understand how to set a unique value to e.g. feature.set('id'). When I create a new layer, or zoom in, the points merge together. It only works as long as you click every button separately and don't zoom.

Comment: Give up is not an option, right? See if helps http://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/8hgxyayp/8/

Comment: Jonatas, I am so much in your debt! I've read through all your answers yesterday-evening and came up with an idea. Here is the result:http://jsfiddle.net/8hgxyayp/9/ This is what I wanted to achieve. Thank you so much for all your help!!!

Comment: What a good news this morning. No debt, you're welcome.

Comment: Hey Jonatas, I am currently using this answer to increase my boundaries of knowledge and I was wondering how'd you know you can use this callback function? I cannot find documentation for this function in the Openlayers API?

Comment: Hey @Abayob, there you are (http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.html#.StyleFunction)